# How to load few files from chosen directory ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Have a following question:
Is it possible to chose folder on client and load all files from this client to server using only ASP.NET app without any additional app on the client side?

I really don't know how it possible or is it possible to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AVD, and how will the `FileUpload` control allow for selecting an entire folder and uploading all the files to the server?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Agree! and that was (FileUpload) for OP's reference. Yes there are some alternatives like - http://ajaxuploader.com/

Comment: @AVD, sure but the question here was not about using third party controls. It was about how to achieve that using pure ASP.NET.  I suppose that the OP is aware that there are third party controls if he is asking how to achieve that without them.

Comment: You could build something yourself, but there are many options available. You could get RequestTimeOut exceptions if you implement it yourself in the wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible using pure HTML and javascript. The closest you could get is HTML5's `<input type="file">` control which allows you to perform multiple file selection. So you could have the user enter inside the folder and then select all files. This could be done by appending the `multiple` attribute:

```
<input type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

Of course the browser that your client is using must support it.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible in internet, but you can do this using HTML application (HTA file on client) that sends the data to ASP.NET WebService. But this solution not acceptable in all cases,

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with normal asp.net.

Take a look at the  [jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/)

> jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin ($.MultiFile) is a non-obstrusive
>   plugin for jQuery that helps users easily select multiple files for
>   upload quickly and easily on your hosting server whilst also providing
>   some basic validation functionality to help developers idenfity simple
>   errors, without having to submit the form